# CardView Click to download PDF

Tags: java, android

i want to download a pdf file when i click on the card view, this is how i declare it inside a viewholder..

```
         holder.pdfLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {

                    final DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                    baptistDatabase.child(post_key).child("pdflocation").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            String baptistpdf = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(baptistpdf);
                            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                            Long reference = dm.enqueue(request);
  }
```

and this is my LogCat

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.packageone.winter.tkpchanmariunitaizawl, PID: 13072
java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:475)
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:465)
    at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:437)
    at com.packageone.winter.tkpchanmariunitaizawl.BaptistS_pdf.BaptistPdfFiles$1$2$1.onDataChange(BaptistPdfFiles.java:108)
```

My Database Goes like this.

```
 Baptists -> Pdf Files -> push() -> (key)pdflocation - "Storage Location Link"
```

How i want is when i Click on the Card view, i just want to Download the Pdf, because i just cant refer to one single Link as it keeps on changing when a new pdf files are uploaded..

Help...